# Error when using stream insertion on parameter of type wstringstream in GCC but not MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17, mingw-w64

I have a header that I've put together to assist with logging in an application using MSVC v141 (Visual Studio 2017). Since these logging utilities are useful, I wanted to bring it into a project I've just started that is using CMake and MinGW/GCC. The header itself should be standalone, it just performs some magic to abstract away common info and stream destinations so that all I have to do is call InitLogging() in my main loop then make calls to LogInfo/LogError/etc, but when I compile against `MinGW(10.3.0 [MSYS2])/GCC(7.5.0 [Ubuntu])`, I am given the following error:

```c
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const wstringstream& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>’
 #define LogInfo(str) { LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER << str, std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER_2);  }
/mnt/d/dev/test_logger/src/main.cpp:9:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘LogInfo’
  LogInfo(L"Test log");
```

Here is the relevant code from the header:

```cpp
std::wstring Time2String();

#define LOG_HELPER __FUNCTION__ << L"(): "
#define LOG_HELPER_2 L"[" << Time2String() << "] "

inline void LogMessage(eLogLevel lvl, const std::wstringstream& str, const std::wstringstream& logHelper);//Snipped definition

#define LogInfo(str) { LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER << str, std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER_2);  }
```

If I simply pass the `std::wstreamstring()`s without any insertions or if I instantiate variables of that type outside of the call and perform the insertions on those variables outside the call, then the compiler is happy, though it is equally unhappy if I try to perform insertions on the variables from the function call similar to the current `#define`.

examples:

```cpp
LogInfo(L"Test log");//compile error

/*******************************************/
std::wstringstream tmpSStream, tmpSStream2;
tmpSStream << LOG_HELPER << L"Test log";
tmpSStream2 << LOG_HELPER_2;
LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, tmpSStream, tmpSStream2);//no error

/*******************************************/
LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, std::wstringstream(), std::wstringstream());//no error

/*******************************************/
std::wstringstream tmpSStream, tmpSStream2;
LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, tmpSStream << LOG_HELPER << L"Test log", tmpSStream2 << LOG_HELPER_2);//compile error
```

Is this a bug in GCC or is MSVC doing something it shouldn't be?

Comment: Suggestion: Check out the return type of `<<`.

Comment: Am not sure what type `__FUNCTION__` is on your platform, but if it's a narrow string I don't think you can do `std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER`

Comment: Simple reproduction: `const std::stringstream & x = std::stringstream() << 10;` I think Visual Studio is being a bit permissive here. The temporary `stringstream` is being returned from `<<`, but in the form of a `std::ostream &`

Comment: I don't have VS 2017, but VS 2015 catches it and spits out *error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'const std::stringstream &'* I wonder if 2017 has added a few more overloads to make this compile or if the compilers being a bit smarter and looking though the `ostream &` to get the true type.

Comment: It is an undocumented feature in MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator<<` returns a reference to the `std::basic_ostream` object it is called on, ie (in this case) it returns `std::wostream&`, not `std::wstringstream&` like you are expecting.  You can't initialize a `const std::wstringstring&` from a `std::wostream&`, hence the error message.

Since your `LogInfo()` macro is creating a new scope with `{}` braces, you can utilize the solution you already discovered:

> If I ... instantiate variables of that type outside of the call and perform the insertions on those variables outside the call, then the compiler is happy

Try this:

```cpp
#define LogInfo(str) { \
    std::wstringstream wss, wss2; \
    wss << LOG_HELPER << str; \
    wss2 << LOG_HELPER_2; \
    LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, wss, wss2); \
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/y3b9Ww)

Otherwise, if you don't want to use local variables then you will need to explicitly type-cast the final `std::wostream&` reference that `operator<<` returns, eg:

```cpp
#define LogInfo(str) { \
    LogMessage(eLogLevel_INFO, \
        static_cast<std::wstringstream&>(std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER << str), \
        static_cast<std::wstringstream&>(std::wstringstream() << LOG_HELPER_2) \
    ); \
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/msS4c2)

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked the return type of the operator. This doesn't really explain what exactly MSVC is doing, but it does elude to it and does generally answer my question (MSVC is doing something helpful, but shady), so I'm going to mark this as accepted. Also worth noting, I knew I could just declare the variables within the new scope of the define, but was trying to avoid having to do so explicitly.